Ho to do Logging testing using Locust?
I have a problem, I want to do some test to a web. Which is: https://phia.accionaconstruccion.com/
When you are in, it change the url to use KeyCloack for logging using Microsoft account. So, after trying it by myself I found a code but using an old version of locust and it does not work:
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task


class UserBehavior(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
        self.login()

    def on_stop(self):
        """ on_stop is called when the TaskSet is stopping """
        self.logout()

    def login(self):
        self.client.post("/app/&response_type=code&scope=openid#/", {"user":"email@email.com", "password":"password"})

    def logout(self):
        self.client.post("/app/&response_type=code&scope=openid#/", {"user":"email@email.com", "password":"password"})


    @task(3)
    def app(self):
        self.client.get("/")

    @task(1)
    def app2(self):
        self.client.get("/")

class UserWait(HttpUser):
    task_set = UserBehavior
    #1000 ms = 1 second
    min_wait = 2000
    max_wait = 3000

And I am clueless about how to do this, because the test I have done before were only about connecting people to an URL but logging them never.
I would appreciate your help.
Thank you.

HI! I havent done any tests with KeyCloak, but maybe this can be an inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58604520/create-keycloak-client-via-rest-api
Locust uses requests under the hood, so it should be simple enough to port that.
Also, you should start by upgrading locust.
